# In Magento 2 after ajax success can't redirect page in admin

Tags: magento2.3, adminhtml, redirect

After ajax success can't redirect page in admin in Magento 2

```
 var redirectUrl = "<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'admin/trackorder/shipinfo' ?>";
 $.ajax({
    url: urlLabel,
    type: "POST",
    data: {counsumerNumber:counsumerNumber,courierService:courierService},
    showLoader: true,
    done: function(data, statusText, xhr){
        var status = xhr.status;
        if(status != 200) window.location = redirectUrl;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
var redirectUrl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('trackorder/shipinfo/index/'); ?>";
     $.ajax({
        url: urlLabel,
        type: "POST",
        data: {counsumerNumber:counsumerNumber,courierService:courierService},
        showLoader: true,
        done: function(data, statusText, xhr){
            var status = xhr.status;
            if(status != 200) window.open(redirectUrl, '_blank');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to redirect on page after success

```
var redirectUrl = "<?php echo $block->getUrl("trackorder/shipinfo"); ?>";
$.ajax({
    url: urlLabel,
    type: "POST",
    data: {counsumerNumber:counsumerNumber,courierService:courierService},
    showLoader: true,
    done: function(data, statusText, xhr){
        var status = xhr.status;
        if(status != 200) window.location.href = redirectUrl;
    }
});
```

Just change `window.location = redirectUrl;` to `window.location.href = redirectUrl;`

and `<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'admin/trackorder/shipinfo' ?>` to `<?php echo $block->getUrl("trackorder/shipinfo"); ?>`

Comment: After makes changes as you told, still  I m getting redirects to the same page  refer here https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/1763419

Comment: Video is private, URL not working. What is your current page URL and what is the new URL that you need?

Comment: current page  url 'trackorder/readytopack/index', new page URL  'trackorder/shipinfo/index', Refer this public URL https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/1763419?key=f8ab216b12d2fb754e6e184d14f91199

Comment: Have you tried this? `<?php echo $block->getUrl("trackorder/shipinfo/index/"); ?>`

Comment: yes, I tried with <?php echo $block->getUrl("trackorder/shipinfo/index/"); ?> but still redirect to same page

Answer (score 0):

In admin, `getBaseUrl` & `getUrl` don't always work if you have `Add Secret Key to URLs` on in the config.

Try This

```
var redirectUrl = '<?= /** @noEscape */ $block->getAdminBaseUrl()?>'+'trackorder/shipinfo';
```